# Openproject Docker Restart > Clean OpenProject

Tags: docker, openproject

i took the docker image of openproject and installed it with the instructions from the "recommended usage" part at my freenas.
https://www.openproject.org/docker/

> sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/openproject/{pgdata,static}
>
> docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name openproject -e SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret \
>    -v /var/lib/openproject/pgdata:/var/openproject/pgdata \
>    -v /var/lib/openproject/static:/var/openproject/assets \
>    openproject/community:latest

When I restart my docker virtual engine, every restart I lose my openproject settings and get a clean installed openproject.

The /var/lib directories are used from openproject, so the data i think is saved.

Whats wrong with my setup?

thank you

Comment: Can you please take a look at the directories on the host system while the docker container is running to see if anything is written into those? Also, how do you start/stop the container?

Comment: hm i reinstalled it and now it works :confused: but :happy: